# Printing MultiPage Forms with a Continuation Page

Tags: c#, printing

I have a dynamically generated Invoice that prints out fine so long as it goes onto a single page.

I have several examples of printing out these forms, where you count the Y Position on the page, but a lot of them seem too simple.

When the examples overflow, they simply set

```
e.HasMorePages = true;
```

in the pDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) event.

However, I need to print a continuation header on each subsequent page to ensure multi page forms can all be related to the same customer and order number.

Is there another event I can catch for printing a second page (I assume not as I can't find one), or do I need to do something like;

```
if (PageIsOverflowing)
{
    e.HasMorePages = true; 
    yPos = 10;
    WriteContinuationPage();
}
```

Apologies for not trying the above, but I dont have Visual Studio here, I have just been searching, trying to find an example that does what I need to do. If no one posts, I will try tomorrow and update this as appropriate

write out the continuation page header when I set  HasMorePages

Comment: PrintPage is just that: it prints a page.  When you set e.HasMorePages to true, you are telling the system to run that PrintPage event again, so you need to keep track of which "row" you last printed and start with the next one after that.  Use the BeginPrint event to set your row index to zero, increment in the PrintPage event.

Comment: Sorry John, I'll remember that in future.
Thanks Lars, I'll give that a go, makes sense, justmenas I need to track if its page 1 or not, so I can show the full header or the continuation.